# not getting full network speed (or even close) of 100 mbps

Tags: embedded, ethernet

When I use rsync on large files it shows a download speed of 2.7 MB/s, or around 22Mbps. When I run ethtool on the NIC, here is the output

```
 Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: external
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```

I found similar readings on the host machine.

When I look at ethtool -i etho I get the following:

```
driver: smsc911x
version: 2008-10-21
firmware-version: 
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: smsc911x.0
supports-statistics: no
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

I double checked the ethernet cables I'm using, and all are at least 5e.
I'm using the LAN9221-ABZJ chip for this project. Is this a firmware issue, too much overhead on the protocols, or is this chip know for not transmitting fast enough?

UPDATE

I checked the speeds with iperf. Going from the server side it was 50Mbps. From the Client side it was 65 Mbps. Also, I had to do this remotely (as in i ssh'd into the one machine to configure it). That seems a little low.

Comment: What's the CPU load on the embedded device while you do this?

Comment: @tink using htop cpu load was between 89- 91% throughout. I needed to ssh through another terminal to look at htop, which brought the rate down to 60 Mbps

Comment: Maybe your suboptimal throughput is CPU bound, then?

Comment: @tink I can also raise the clk frequency. Ill let you know the results when I can make those changes

Comment: @tink when I raised the clk frequency, cpu usage maxed out at 80 % and the rate was 88 Mbps.

Comment: Heh .. glad I helped ;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Cpu usage through htop while it is transmitting data. If it is maxed out during ethernet events, it is a good sign that your cpu is the bottleneck. The only fixes are to increase the clock of your cpu, or to get a faster one.